# C - How can this simple transaction() function be completely free of deadlocks?

Tags: c, transactions, deadlock, transpose

So I have this basic transaction() function written in C:

```
void transaction (Account from, Account to, double amount) {

    mutex lock1, lock2;
    lock1 = get_lock(from);
    lock2 = get_lock(to);

    acquire(lock1);
        acquire(lock2);

            withdraw(from, amount);
            deposit(to, amount);

    release(lock2);
    release (lock1);

}
```

It's to my understanding that the function is mostly deadlock-free since the function locks one account and then the other (instead of locking one, making changes, and then locking another). However, if this function was called simultaneously by these two calls:

```
transaction (savings_account, checking_account, 500);

transaction (checking_account, savings_account, 300);
```

I am told that this would result in a deadlock. How can I edit this function so that it's completely free of deadlocks?

Comment: There's no sensible notion of mutex that allows assignment in the way you have it. Mutexes have sort of "unique ownership". Also, you really should try harder to not confuse mutexes and locks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a total ordering of objects (Account objects, in this case) and then always lock them in the same order, according to that total ordering. You can decide what order to lock them in, but the simple thing would be to first lock the one that comes first in the total ordering, then the other.

For example, let's say each account has an account number, which is a unique* integer. (* meaning no two accounts have the same number) Then you could always lock the one with the smaller account number first. Using your example:

```
void transaction (Account from, Account to, double amount)
{
    mutex first_lock, second_lock;

    if (acct_no(from) < acct_no(to))
    {
        first_lock  = get_lock(from);
        second_lock = get_lock(to);
    }
    else
    {
        assert(acct_no(to) < acct_no(from)); // total ordering, so == is not possible!
        assert(acct_no(to) != acct_no(from)); // this assert is essentially equivalent

        first_lock  = get_lock(to);
        second_lock = get_lock(from);
    }

    acquire(first_lock);
    acquire(second_lock);

    withdraw(from, amount);
    deposit(to, amount);

    release(second_lock);
    release(first_lock);
}
```

So following this example, if checking_account has account no. 1 and savings_account has account no. 2, `transaction (savings_account, checking_account, 500);` will lock checking_account first and then savings_account, and `transaction (checking_account, savings_account, 300);` will also lock checking_account first and then savings_account.

If you don't have account numbers (say your working with class Foo instead of class Account) then you need to find something else to establish a total ordering. If each object has a name, as a string, then you can do an alphabetic comparison to determine which string is "less". Or you can use any other type that is comparable for > and <.

However, it is very important that the values be unique for each and every object! If two objects have the same value in whichever field you're testing, then they in the same spot in the ordering. If that can happen, then it is a "partial ordering" not a "total ordering" and it is important to have a total ordering for this locking application.

If necessary, you can make up a "key value" that is an arbitrary number that doesn't mean anything, but is guaranteed unique for each object of that type. Assign a new, unique value to each object when it is created.

Another alternative is to keep all the objects of that type in some kind of list. Then their list position serves to put them in a total ordering. (Frankly, the "key value" approach is better, but some applications may be keeping the objects in a list already for application logic purposes so you can leverage the existing list in that case.) However, take care that you don't end up taking O(n) time (instead of O(1) like the other approaches*) to determine which one comes first in the total ordering when you use this approach.

(* If you're using a string to determine total ordering, then it's not really O(1), but it's linear with the length of the strings and constant w.r.t. the number of objects that hold those strings... However, depending on your application, the string length may be much more reasonably bounded than the numer of objects.)

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! BTW, I'm not 100% sure this is the _only_ way to solve the problem... but I know it does solve the problem, and I can't think of another way off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are trying to solve is called the dining philosophers problem, it is a well known concurrency problem.

In your case the naive solution would be to change acquire to receive 2 parameters(to and from) and only return when it can get both locks at the same time and to not get any lock if it can't have both (because that's the situation when the deadlock may occur, when get 1 lock and wait for the other). Read about the dining philosophers problem and you'll understand why.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I looked it up and it was a very interested read! Thanks for the insight!